# How to store a complete sentence with white spaces in a string in cpp?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I want to store "What is wrong with you?" in a string str in cpp but when I run this code it only stores "What" in ·str·.

How can I store the complete sentence in the string.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string str;
    cin>>str;
    cout<<str;
}
```

Input:

```
What is wrong with you?
```

Output:

```
What
```

Comment: What if you type `What\ is\ wrong\ with\ you?` ? Just to check

Comment: C != C++ and you should generally only tag the language you are writing/compiling.

Comment: just **stop using `istream::operator>>` already!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

was already answered. But here is the solution:

```
std::string str; 
std::getline( std::cin, str);
```